# Como salvar um Inner Join?

Tags: sql, mysqli, join, mysql, inner-join

Fiz um `INNER JOIN` em meu banco no `mysql workbench` ,porém quando eu fecho o `SELECT` e abro a tabela novamente ele volta ao normal, com as colunas da forma antes do `INNER JOIN`.

Gostaria de saber como posso salvar esse `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT nome,camisa,posicao,situacao,selecao
FROM jogador
INNER JOIN pais ON jogador.pais_idpais = pais.id_pais;
```

Answer (score 0):

O comando SELECT apenas trabalha a informação disponível em uma ou mais tabelas e as apresenta de uma determinada forma, não as altera.
O que está a querer fazer requer uma de duas possibilidades:

- Cristalizar o resultado para consulta futura;
- Facilitar a visualização da mesma informação numa execução posterior.

Para a primeira é necessário criar uma tabela nova com a estrutura da informação a ser visualizada e registar nela o resultado da pesquisa. Existem mecanismos em alguns motores de BD que permitem a criação da tabela apartir do resultado da pesquisa (`INSERT SELECT`).

A segunda obtêm-se através daa noção de vista (`VIEW`). Esta noção permite a abstracção da pesquisa original através de um alias (`CREATE VIEW view_name`) que pode ser invocado numa nova pesquisa. Desta forma, uma pesquisa extensa e complicada pode ser facilmente invocada através `SELECT * FROM view_name`. Para a generalidade dos cenários de uso as vistas são como tabelas... não tendo a informação que lhes deu origem agarrada (existe um conceito intermédio de vistas materializadas - `MATERIALIZED_VIEW` - que não se aplicará aqui

As duas abordagem tem vantagens e desvantagens que tem de ser tidas em conta na escolha da solução.

Atendendo ao (pouco) que é exposto, parece-me que a `vista` faz mais sentido.
Usando o exemplo fornecido, esta pode ser criada através do comando:

```
CREATE VIEW formacao_equipas AS 
  SELECT nome, camisa, posicao, situacao, selecao FROM jogador INNER JOIN pais ON jogador.pais_idpais = pais.id_pais;
```

Depois disso, a informação pode ser consultada através da expressão:

```
SELECT * FROM formacao_equipas;
```

Condições adicionais podem ser acrescentadas à pesquisa sobre a view e os resultados que são apresentados reflectem essas condições.

```
SELECT * FROM formacao_equipas WHERE posicao = 'Guarda-Redes';
```

retornaria a lista de todos os jogadores que ocupam a posição de 'Guarda-Redes' (não sabendo o tipo de dados da coluna 'posicao').